# How can I download a folder as Zip-File?

Tags: php, download, zip, directory

I have a folder with images on my website. When I load my page an automatic download of the folder as Zip-File should start.

```
$dir = 'gallery/1/';
$zip_file = 'file.zip';

// Get real path for our folder
$rootPath = realpath($dir);

// Initialize archive object
$zip = new ZipArchive();
$zip->open($zip_file, ZipArchive::CREATE | ZipArchive::OVERWRITE);

// Create recursive directory iterator
/** @var SplFileInfo[] $files */
$files = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
    new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($rootPath),
    RecursiveIteratorIterator::LEAVES_ONLY
);

foreach ($files as $name => $file)
{
    // Skip directories (they would be added automatically)
    if (!$file->isDir())
    {
        // Get real and relative path for current file
        $filePath = $file->getRealPath();
        $relativePath = substr($filePath, strlen($rootPath) + 1);

        // Add current file to archive
        $zip->addFile($filePath, $relativePath);
    }
}

// Zip archive will be created only after closing object
$zip->close();


header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($zip_file));
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($zip_file));
readfile($zip_file);
```

But when I load my page, nothing happens.

Comment: i there a  question

Comment: Have you checked the error log?

Comment: @KIKOSoftware I am using ` error_reporting(E_ALL);` but there are no errors displayed. It is just not happening anything when I load the page

Comment: i have test your code & seems working fine, downloaded a zip file

Comment: @AZinkey This is strange. Why is it not working then on my page...

Comment: try header("Content-Type: application/zip");

Comment: any pop up blocker ?

Comment: @AZinkey Tested. But still nothing is downloaded

Comment: @AZinkey No, no Blocker, I tested it in different browsers

Comment: I just get downvotes and no hint, why my code is not working. I just do not understand at all

Comment: Downvotes are probably due to the words 'nothing happens', because it is not a good way to describe a problem. It simply means you haven't done any debugging at all. You should. So put an echo in your code, does it end up in the output? If not then the script doesn't execute, which could also explain why you don't see any errors in the output. That's why I asked about the error log. And so on... basic debugging steps should be followed before you ask a question.

Comment: I was debugging, but the was no output

Comment: Finally I found out what caused the problem! The php code MUST be on the very top of the page before all html code. Then it is working!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The php code must be on top of the page. There should not be any other html code before it